# How to binding Helix-MeshGeometryVisual3D in codebehind?

Tags: wpf, xaml, code-behind, helix-3d-toolkit

How can I implement the following XAML with the Code-Behind?

```
 <helix:MeshGeometryVisual3D MeshGeometry="{Binding TextGeometry}" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
var geometry = new MeshGeometryVisual3D
{
    MeshGeometry = TextGeometry,
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I mistakenly was looking for `SetBinding` or something like that. While it has been much easier.